# Ошибка аутентификации GIT

Tags: git, plesk

Создал репозиторий на Plesk, при **"git push origin master"** получаю ошибку:

> fatal: Authentication failed for
>   'https://user@domain.com/plesk-git/domain.git/'

Логи:

> AH01617: user user: authentication failure for
>   "/plesk-git/domain.git/info/refs": Password Mismatch

Пароль системного пользователя FTP поменял несколько раз, ввожу точно правильно.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А при чём тут ftp?

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что нужно вводить логин/пароль юзера-владельца репозитория? Либо котрибьютора?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, Git не умеет FTP.

Comment: @AlexeyTen В документации по Plesk написано: "В настоящее время репозитории Git в Plesk защищены паролем FTP-пользователя. Анонимный доступ не поддерживается."

Comment: Тогда этот вопрос надо задать в техподдержку хостера

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была на стороне хостинга, служба поддержки помогла.

> Дело в некоторых настройках сервера, которые мешают работе git. Чтобы
>   устранить проблему нам необходимо перенести Вашу услугу на другой
>   сервер.